# iOS dynamic cell height based off dynamic textview based off text

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, tableview, frame

I am trying to get my `UITableViewCell` to resize properly based off a `textview` which is dynamically sized based off it's text. However I can't get them to all work together. Below is what I have so far? Right now the cell height is correct, but the `textView` isn't being resized based off the `contentSize.height`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the label properties!
    self.titleLabel.text = self.releaseTitle;
    self.pubDateLabel.text = self.pubDate;
    self.attachmentsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.attatchments.count];
    self.contentTextView.text = self.summary;    
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Set the proper height of the content cell of the text
    CGRect frame = self.contentTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.contentTextView.contentSize.height;
    self.contentTextView.frame = frame;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return self.contentTextView.contentSize.height;
}
```

Comment: try https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/autoresizingeditabletableviewcell it is tested and works fine.

Comment: I would rather not have to subclass a UITableViewCell, especially with iOS7 coming out...

Comment: when calling viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: don't forget to add [super viewWillAppear:animated] and [super viewDidAppear:animated] ;)

Comment: Can you try to call sizeToFit method in contentTextView?

Comment: Nope, that does not work.

Comment: UITableViewCell is really designed to be subclassed. Especially if you're putting TextFields in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the height of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath,` something like

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *theText=[[_loadedNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] name];
CGSize labelSize = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"FontA" size: 15.0f] constrainedToSize:kLabelFrameMaxSize];
return kHeightWithoutLabel+labelSize.height;
```

}

You can set some constraints on the label size by setting `kLabelFrameMaxSize`

```
#define kLabelFrameMaxSize CGSizeMake(265.0, 200.0)
```

Then you return the height by adding a constant height with the variable label height.

Also, to be consistent, you should use the same methodology to set the frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of using `sizeToFitMultipleLines`

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
FQCustomCell *_customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
if (_customCell == nil) {
    _customCell = [[FQCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier: @"CustomCell"];
}


_customCell.myLabel.text = [[_loadedNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] name];
_customCell.myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"FontA" size: 15.0f];

UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_customCell.backgroundView = backView;

CGSize labelSize = [_customCell.myLabel.text sizeWithFont:_customCell.myLabel.font constrainedToSize:kLabelFrameMaxSize];
_customCell.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);

return _customCell;
}
```

You can alter this for UILabel, UIButton, Cell.

Comment: sizeWithFont: is now deprecated. You would have to use boundingRectWithSize. See my updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814755/ios-size-table-row-based-on-content-in-textview

Comment: @Jon Erickson mention the exact version of IOS you are going to deploy.

Comment: in iOS7 sizeWithFont is deprecated.